# How to change NSIS Error message about CRCCheck

Tags: nsis, crc

Some of my users are complaining about some odd errors my installers had after downloading them from my web server.

This are NSIS installer that when downloaded came crippled or incomplete (usually because of slow Internet connections), the message is very clear "The installer you are trying to use is corrupted or incomplete....." IN ENGLISH!! (Did I mention my users only speak Spanish?).

How do I change the language or create custom error messages?

I already create the installer in Spanish by using:

```
; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

The CRC check runs before you/nsis can access the langstrings, so the only way to change this message is to recompile the source code.

The message was changed several versions ago and now includes a URL to the NSIS wiki, one would think your users would be able to run a translator on that page

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done an NSIS package since it was referred to as Super Pimp (great name). See if this helps:
[NSIS Language Table](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Adding_Language_strings_as_resources)

Comment: Yeah I already had a look on that but on step 2 http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Adding_Language_strings_as_resources#Step_2, they disable CRCCheck so the altered messages doesn't trigger the CRC message :P.

Comment: Hmm...that is a bit counterproductive for you huh?

Comment: Yeah I guess, I really want the users to be alerted about downloading an incomplete file....